# Connecting to Twitter with Android

Tags: android, twitter

I am currently trying to DL some twitter information and for some reason the code that I am using will not return the data.

When I use the URL manually in Explorer I do get data. but when I try to get Android to do it I get an exception.

I have found two ways of trying to get at the data.  The first is as shown. The second is commenting out the three lines above the comments and uncommenting the other lines.

I will be using JSON simple afterwards in order to parse the string.

I hope I have explained my issue sufficiently.  Any comments would be welcome.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@aplusk&rpp=100&page=1";


    HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    Log.d("log", "test"+responseBody);
    try{
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
        responseBody =  response.toString();


//          HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
//          InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
//          responseBody = inputStream.toString();

        Log.d("log", "test2"+responseBody);

    }catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.d("log", "nope");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exception is, but your first problem is probably that you're doing network activity on the main thread. You'll have to spin up a new thread or use an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Your second problem is you're improperly converting the response to a string. To get the actual content string you'll have to iterate over an InputStream. [This is my preferred method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/645387).

Also, make sure `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Try this out:

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        (new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@aplusk&rpp=100&page=1";
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

                String responseBody = null;
                Log.d("log", "test" + responseBody);
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
                    InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    // responseBody = inputStream.toString();
                    responseBody = streamToString(inputStream);

                    Log.d("log", "test2" + responseBody);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.d("log", "nope");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        })).start();
    }

    public static String streamToString(InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: So. My entire issue wasnt the code but where it was placed?  Eventually it was supposed to be added to a service that I was going to use but i was trying to test it just to get it to return data and parse it.  Since I had never done anything with using a URL I wanted to make sure it would work before adding it to my actual project.  Seems kind of silly that I cannot run a basic request in a blank project like the one above in order to verify that what I am doing is a waste of time or not.